# How to display specific parameters from link in URL with htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What.htaccess code should I write to turn something like

```
localhost/article.php?id=something&number=something
```

into just

```
localhost/article/id
```

Thoughts guys?

Comment: First show us some code you've already tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rules like this in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+article\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ article/%1? [R=302,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^article/([^/]+)/?$ article.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask how to change that to localhost/article/id

Comment: When I try to visit http://localhost/article.php?id=something&number=10    the redirection is not working for some reason.

Comment: Nevermind, it worked! Only problem I have now is that when I hover over the link, the real link shows. Any way to change that?

Comment: hover link cannot be changed by rewrite rule but after you click it can be changed. Its better to change your HTML accordingly with pretty URLs